# Django template inheritance: repetitive views

Tags: django, django-views, template-inheritance

I have a view called ListAEQ:

```
class ListAEQ(MixinView, ListView):
    template_name = 'allometric/aeq_list.html'
    model = Equation

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (Equation.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user))
```

I want to use the queryset from this view multiple times with different templates.  For example I have a template that extends aeq_list.html, that replaces a block in the parent template with different content.  How do I render this content using the same view but different templates, without having to create multiple views that have the same queryset and a different tempate_name.  I believe there is a way to do this according to the principle "DRY"

For example, I would create a new view

```
class ListAEQindia(MixinView, ListView):
    template_name = 'allometric/aeq_list_india.html'
    model = Equation

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (Equation.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you're determining which template is to be rendered. But presuming it's based on a parameter from the URL, you can define the `get_template_names`method in your view.

That method can access self.kwargs and self.request etc and then return a list containing the name of the template to use. (Note that it does have to be a list, even if the list only contains one item.)

Comment: so inside
    ListAEQ(MixinView, ListView):

i would define
    def get_template_names():
and have that function return a list with all possible child templates?

Comment: No, you have it return the single relevant template considering the request.

Comment: Ahhh I see! so I use logic to determine the template_name based on kwargs and then set template_name equal to the template i want